# Side by side elements without float, position: absolute, display: block / inline-block, flexbox or grid

Tags: css, puppeteer

I have a very annoying problem. I need to have elements be side by side without using the usually techniques like `float`, `position: absolute`, `display: block`, `display: inline-block`, `flexbox` or `grid`.

The reason is that `page-break-before: always;` doesn't work on on elements with above CSS attributes when using `puppeteer`.

Comment: use table where you don't even need to add CSS

Comment: I don't have the possibility of using tables

Comment: I would solve the problem differently; Change the tool your are using (the puppeteer) because it seems to not allow you do anything. I don't see how to get something if you cannot apply CSS and your aren't allowed to use the most basic stuff (tables)

Comment: You can use <span> or other inline" elements. Please attach mockup or code.